# Confused on the use of exec(family) in Unix

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork, pipe

I'm writing a program in which I use the system call fork() to create a child process, and then create a grandchild, as well as creating a pipe between the child and grandchild. I think my implementation is fairly good, however when I run the program, it simply skips right through the prompts in my code.

Essentially we have this:

-Process starts
Fork() create child
Child creates pipe
Fork() creates grandchild, pipe inherited.

TL;DR- Code skips through UI prompts, not sure if I'm entering data correctly, not sure if I'm reading data into processes correctly.

How do I read inputs down the pipe?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int p[2];
        int pid, pid2;

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
                pipe(p);
                pid2 = fork();

                switch(pid2)
                {
                        case -1:
                                printf("CASE 1");
                                exit(-1);
                        case 0:
                                close(0);
                                dup(p[0]);
                                close(p[0]);
                                close(p[1]);
                                execl("./Sort/sort", 0);
                                break;
                        default:
                                close(1);
                                dup(p[1]);
                                close(p[1]);
                                close(p[0]);
                                execl("./Pre/pre", 0);
                                break;
                }
          }
          else
          {
                wait(pid);
                printf("Process Completed\n");
                exit(0);
           }
}
```

Child process for pre:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char n1[20];
        int g1;
        FILE *ofp, *ifp;
        int track;

        ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

        while(track != -1)
        {
                printf("Please enter the student's grade and then name, ");
                printf("separated by a space: ");
                scanf("%3d %s", &g1, n1);

                if (g1 >= 60)
                {
                        fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", n1);
                }

                printf("Add another name?(-1 to quit, 0 to continue): ");
                scanf("%d", &track);
        }
        fclose(ofp);

        ifp = fopen("output.txt", "r");
        printf("Students that made a 60+:\n");
        while(fscanf(ifp, "%s", n1) == 1)
                printf("%s\n", n1);

        fclose(ifp);
```

Child process for sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int stringcmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int i = 0;
     int num = 0;
     int j = 0;
     char name[20];

          printf("How many names would you like to enter? ");
          scanf("%d", &num);

          char **input = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));

          for (i=0; i < num; i++)
          {
                printf("Please input a name(first only): ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                input[i] = strdup(name);
          }

          qsort(input, num, sizeof(char *), stringcmp);

          printf("Names:\n");

          for(j = 0; j < num; j++)
               printf("%s\n", input[j]);


          for( i = 0; i < num; i++ ) free(input[i]);
          free(input);
```

Comment: Please add source of the child processes, it will be easier to reproduce the behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that `pre` *outputs prompts to stdout*. That text will end up in the pipe, which is going to end up in `sort`'s `stdin`.

You should `fprintf` all your prompts to `stderr`.

`pre` also doesn't output text in the format expected by `sort`; `sort` expects an integer `n` followed by `n` words (first names). So, that should be the *only* text that `pre` outputs on `stdout`; everything else needs to go to a file or `stderr`.

P.S. Also, use `dup2(p[0], 0)` instead of `close(0); dup(p[0])` as it makes your intent clearer, as well as potentially avoiding threading issues (of course only relevant if you have threads, but it's worth keeping in mind).

Comment: Thanks for the dup tip, my professor had only ever explained it the way I implemented it. As far as printing all the prompts to stderr, would it just be easier to remove the prompts altogether, and have the output from pre read straight in to sort? Or would this cause a problem?

Comment: Yes, I don't see a great reason for the prompts unless you want some kind of interactive mode.  There shouldn't be a difference in functionality if you remove the prompts vs pushing those to stderr.

Comment: Perfect. That was what I was confused about. I wasn't sure if the prompts had to be there in order to interface with the pipe, although in typing that statement, I feel stupid for thinking that! :P

Comment: Well, if you want to interact with `pre` interactively (possibly through `sort`), then the prompts are useful to have. But I agree with @Michael: they are not crucial.

Comment: Last question: Should the fscanf's and fprintf's be changed to scanf/printf respectively? Or will the output (due to the close/dup) be changed to the pipe regardless?

Comment: The existing `fscanf/fprintf` are doing I/O with a file, which is totally separate from the `stdin`/`stdout` stuff. They don't need to be changed at all.

Comment: The main problem I am dealing with now, is the fact that I think the grandchild process is running prior to it's input from pre. What I mean is, the child process is waiting to execute until AFTER the grandchild, giving the sort(grandchild) no data to process. Its a requirement of the assignment that the Child->Pre and Grandchild->Sort. Is there any way to have the grandchild wait on the child to finish first?

Comment: Well, it's homework...give it some thought and do your own research. Come back to SO with a clear question if you really get stuck, but remember: you learn best when you discover the answers for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's are two examples of how to do it

1. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html
2. http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Edit: I can tell that you are trying to pipe the output of "./Pre/pre" to the input of "./Sort/sort" but I'm not sure what you mean by "Code skips through UI prompts" because for `case 1:` and `default:` you don't have any prompts. What exactly is the problem? If you want something more specific please explain more of the details in your question.

Comment: Essentially, I'm using execl to call two programs I've already written. When it starts, I read in a text file automatically into the "pre" call (default switch). The problem is, I'm not sure how they're supposed to make the transition down the pipe, to provide sufficient data for the "sort" call at the end of the pipe. Does the data output from pre have to be structured a certain way for sort to handle it correctly?

Edit: I actually used both of those sites for reference while crafting my current code :P